# SVG click and switch

Tags: javascript, html, svg

---

```
<svg>
  <a id="T" class="toggle" xlink:href="#0">
  <circle cx="238.1" cy="43.71" r="7.93" fill="#000" />
  </a>
  <a id="Y" class="toggle" xlink:href="#0">
  <circle cx="270.58" cy="119.2" r="6.93" fill="#000"/>
  </a>
  <a id="H" class="toggle" xlink:href="#0">
  <circle cx="203.7" cy="114.11" r="6.93" fill="#000"/>
  </a>
```

```
<div id="T_box" class="hide"><h1>........T.......</h1></div>
<div id="Y_box" class="hide"><h1>........Y........</h1></div>
enter code here
```

---

Many thanks, @NewToJS

But this still cannot switch.......
I need A to appear, but when clicking B, A disappears, and show B

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle')).forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', function() {
document.getElementById(a.id + '_box').classList.toggle('hide');
  });});
```

---

```
.hide {display: none;}
div {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);}
```

Comment: For starters, your first click handler's missing a callback function.

Comment: You also have a `CSS` error. You need to remove the comma from the end of `.show_H,`

Comment: Maybe this example might be of some use. I have cleaned up the source code [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/4yp0bkae/)

Comment: Why do you use SVG for this?

Comment: Thanks, @NewToJS, but that example did not switch, I need it ...click A and show A, but when click B.....A will close, and B will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are trying to do is a simple toggle function, you might optimize it and clean it, but at the end it will come down to hide everyone and show the one you need every time.

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle')).forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('toggle')).forEach(i => {
   document.getElementById(i.id + '_box').classList.add('hide');
  });
    document.getElementById(a.id + '_box').classList.remove('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg>
      <a id="T" class="toggle" xlink:href="#0">
       <circle cx="238.1" cy="43.71" r="7.93" fill="#000" />
      </a>
      <a id="Y" class="toggle" xlink:href="#0">
       <circle cx="270.58" cy="119.2" r="6.93" fill="#000"/>
      </a>
      <a id="H" class="toggle" xlink:href="#0">
       <circle cx="203.7" cy="114.11" r="6.93" fill="#000"/>
      </a>
<svg>
<h1 id="T_box">A</h1>
<h1 id="Y_box" class="hide">B</h1>
<h1 id="H_box" class="hide">C</h1>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `<a>`, you can make use of `:target`.

```css
h1 {
  display: none;
}
h1:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg>
      <a id="T" class="toggle" xlink:href="#T_box">
       <circle cx="238.1" cy="43.71" r="7.93" fill="#000" />
      </a>
      <a id="Y" class="toggle" xlink:href="#Y_box">
       <circle cx="270.58" cy="119.2" r="6.93" fill="#000"/>
      </a>
      <a id="H" class="toggle" xlink:href="#H_box">
       <circle cx="203.7" cy="114.11" r="6.93" fill="#000"/>
      </a>
<svg>
<h1 id="T_box">A</h1>
<h1 id="Y_box">B</h1>
<h1 id="H_box">C</h1>
```